Accessing pokeapi - taking a long time
I want to get a list of names of pokemon from the first 150 that have a hp less than a particular value.
Here's what I've got so far:
def get_pokemon_with_similar_hp(max_hp):
    pokemon_names = []
    poke_data = []
    for i in range(1, 151):
        api_url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{i}"
        pokemon_response = requests.get(api_url)
        pokemon_data = pokemon_response.json()
        poke_data.append(pokemon_data)
    
    for j in range(0, 150):
        if poke_data[j]['stats'][0]['base_stat'] < max_hp:
                pokemon_names.append(poke_data[j]['name'])
    return pokemon_names   

This works, and gives me the data I want, but it's currently taking 8.49 s to process and send through to my frontend. Is there a way of improving my code to speed things up? Many thanks in advance :)

According to the API documentation you can use GraphQL query, so you can do this in one request. E.g.:
import requests

graphql_url = "https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/v1beta"


# https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/console/
payload = {
    "operationName": "samplePokeAPIquery",
    "query": r"query samplePokeAPIquery($maxhp: Int) {pokemon_v2_pokemon(where: {pokemon_v2_pokemonstats: {base_stat: {_lt: $maxhp}}}) {id name}}",
    "variables": {"maxhp": 100},
}

data = requests.post(graphql_url, json=payload)
print(json.dumps(data.json(), indent=4))

Prints:
{
    "data": {
        "pokemon_v2_pokemon": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "bulbasaur"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "ivysaur"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "venusaur"
            },

...


Fantastic - thank you so much!!! I was able to limit my request to the first 151 pokemon by doing the following:
query samplePokeAPIquery($maxhp: Int) {pokemon_v2_pokemon (where: {pokemon_v2_pokemonstats: {base_stat: {_lt: $maxhp}}, id: {_lte: 151}}) {id name}}

This is the final query I used:
query samplePokeAPIquery($maxhp: Int) {pokemon_v2_pokemon (where: {pokemon_v2_pokemonstats: {stat_id: {_eq: 1}, _and: {base_stat: {_lte: $maxhp}}}, id: {_lte: 151}}) {name}}
I had to provide the id of the stat as it was previously finding pokemon where any stat was less than the given number, not just the hp
